# Twilio - how to tell if incoming call while on another call in Client Browser

Tags: api, browser, client, twilio, phone-call

If a call is incoming when using a Client Browser (twilio.js) and I am already connected to an active call in the Client Browser. Client Browser doesn't ring or given any indication of an incoming call while I'm already on a call with someone else.

Is this a bug? What can be done about it so I can tell if there is an incoming call? I need to be able to answer that 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc... incoming call should I have multiple people calling my Twilio number at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a late reply but you can use the `Enqueue` verb to place your callers in a queue, and then use the REST API with a javascript `setInterval` to list the callers in the queue.  After that you can dequeue them with a `Dial` method or via the REST API.

We have crafted call-center functionality in node using a similar method where callers are placed in a queue which triggers a `setInterval` loop that monitors the queue for its members, and also looks for available agents to call.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested I have solved this problem for myself, but in a different way to what @Ding suggests.

I'm not sure if the API has changed since this questions but you are able to access multiple Connections from a single Twilio.Device(). See this question for more details: [Twilio call routing/management for small customer service team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388536/twilio-call-routing-management-for-small-customer-service-team/55622509#55622509)